# Cupy streams synchronization using with statement

Tags: stream, cuda, cupy

Are the two codes equivalent?

Code 1:

```
with cp.cuda.Stream(non_blocking=False) as stream:
    # do stuff
    stream.synchronize()
```

Code 2:

```
with cp.cuda.Stream(non_blocking=False) as stream:
    # do stuff
stream.synchronize()
```

Comment: So it is possible that the stream never completes because the stream could get deleted before completing the synchronization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, these two are equivalent. `with cp.cuda.Stream(non_blocking=False) as stream:` switches the [current stream](https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/user_guide/basic.html#current-stream) of CuPy, i.e., all the code within the block will be performed on `stream`.

In CuPy, streams are not synchronized automatically on exiting the context manager so that users can fully control the synchronization timing. This is handy when dealing with multiple streams, e.g.:

```py
s1 = cp.cuda.Stream(non_blocking=False)
s2 = cp.cuda.Stream(non_blocking=False)

for i in range(10):
    with s1:
        # do some work
    with s2:
        # do some work

s1.synchronize()
s2.synchronize()
```